# Finding the potential for a point charge in front of an infinite long grounded conductive rod

Tags: electrostatics, boundary-conditions, greens-functions

So, I am given the following 2D Green's function:

$G(\vec r, \vec r')=\frac 1 {2\pi}\log(c \cdot |\vec r - \vec r'|) \ $ which can also be expressed in polar coordinates $G(\rho)=\frac 1 {2\pi}\log(c \cdot \rho)$. Small $c$ is just some constant.

Now I am asked to find the potential for $y>0$ when a point charge is located along the positive side of the $y$-axis in an arbitrary location $(0,d)$ and the conductive rod is along the $x$-axis and is grounded.
I am given two boundary conditions:

1. The potential on the rod $\Phi(x,0)=0$.
2. At infinity the potential becomes zero. So when $\rho$ becomes too large, the potential vanishes.

This is what I do:
Notation:

1. $\vec r$ an arbitrary location in which we want to know the potential.
2. $\vec r'$ vector pointing at the source, in this case the point charge.
3. $\vec r'_s$ vector pointing in the mirror charge, located at $(0,-d)$.
4. $\bar{\vec r} \ $ a position vector pointing in the conductive surface, where our Green's function should be $0$.

Then:
$$G(\vec r,\vec r')= \frac 1 {2\pi}\log(c \cdot |\vec r - \vec r'|) + F(\vec r,\vec r')$$ where $F(\vec r, \vec r')$ is the potential of the mirror charge

$$G(\vec r, \vec r')|_{\vec r=\bar{\vec r}}=0$$

This implies that: $F(\vec r, \vec r'_s)= \frac 1 {2\pi}\log(c \cdot |\bar {\vec r} - \vec r'_s|)$

If you plug in for $\vec r=(x,y)$ and for $\vec r' =(0,d)$ and $\vec r'_s=(0,-d)$ you will see that the Green's function vanishes, is equal to zero, which is what we want.

Then in the general case where the source can be located at any point we have:

$$G(\vec r, \vec r') = \frac 1 {4 \pi} \log\left(\frac {x^2 + (y-d)^2}{x^2 + (y+d)^2}\right)$$

The potential, when we have the present one around the source of an external electric field of a conductor, or many is:

$$\Phi (\vec r) = \int_V G(\vec r, \vec r') \rho(\vec r')dV'   + \sum_i \Phi_i\cdot \Gamma_i$$ where $\Gamma_i$ are the geometric coefficients of the conductors. In my specific case, the conductor is grounded, hence the potential is zero and that last term vanishes.

If I also take into consideration that the charge density of the point charge can be expressed as follows:

$\rho(\vec r')=Q \cdot \delta (\vec r_+ -\vec r')$, where $\vec r_+ = (0,d) \ $ is the location of my point charge.

When I implement this expression for the charge density in my expression for the potential, I end up with:

$$\Phi(\vec r)=\frac Q {4 \pi} \log \left(\frac {x^2 + (y-d)^2}{x^2 + (y+d)^2}\right)$$

But the proper answer would be:

$$\Phi(\vec r)=-\frac Q {4 \pi \epsilon_0} \log \left(\frac {x^2 + (y-d)^2}{x^2 + (y+d)^2}\right)$$

So I am missing a minus sign and the permittivity constant. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you made a typo with $G(\vec r, \vec r')|_{\vec r=\bar{\vec r}}=0$ in the $\bar{\vec r}$ part? Should it be:  $G(\vec r, \vec r')|_{\vec r=\vec r'}=0$?

Comment: No. What I am implying is that when the vector $\vec r$ points somewhere in the surface of the conductor then you have the green's function equal to zero. Since the green function is simetric, even if $\vec r'$ (position vector of the source charge) points in the surface of the conductor you would still get zero.

Comment: Can you explain what this means: "The potential when we have present around the source of external electric field a conductor..."? I read it as: "The potential, when we have the present one around the source of an external electric field of a conductor..."

Comment: the potential in space is different when you have a charge distribution and when you have a charge distribution + conductors

Comment: There are various conventions for factors of $\pi$, $\epsilon_0$, and minus one in the Green's function and $\Phi$. All should yield the same correct answer. Check how your equation for $\Phi$ is derived, and for what convention of $G$. Also, your Green's function has $G(r,r')$ on the left but no primes on the right

Comment: In SI units Poisson's law looks like this $\Delta \phi = \frac{rho}{\epsilon}$ So if one assumes a negative point charge one has: $\Delta \phi = -\frac{Q}{\epsilon}\delta^(3)(\vec{r-r'})$. This way you get the factors in. Because the Green's function solves:  $\Delta G(\vec{r-r'}) =\delta^(3)(\vec{r-r'})$.